# WCF Data Services Toolkit with CTP2

Tags: wcf, odata, toolkit

Im trying to use the WCF Data Services Toolkit together with Microsoft WCF Data Services March 2011 CTP 2 for .NET Framework 4 and Silverlight 4. But When i use this release i get multiple compile errors regarding missing reference to System.Data.Services. Of course i can't reference that assembly, since i already reference Microsoft. Data.Services and will get alot of "multiple types" error. To me it seems like WCF toolkit has been compiled against the System.Data.Services that ships with .Net 4 and the compiler needs a reference even though im not using any types from that assembly.

So how on earth is Jonathan Carter in the [MIX 11 session](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/FRM16) able to reference only Microsoft.Data.Services and use the toolkit without any compilation errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected, the answer is to recompile the source yourself against the CTP binaries.

http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/13

I ended up doing that myself, after watching and rewatching the MIX11 session a thousand times following whatever Jonathan did down to the last detail.